# CUstom button to change color on focus and focus lost

Tags: c#, forms, focus, custom-controls

Hi Iam trying to make a custom button that has a gradient color that changes when another button is clicked. This is the code i amusing

```
public class GradientButton : Button
{
    private Color _Color1 = Color.LightSteelBlue;
    private Color _Color2 = Color.White;
    private Color _Color3 = Color.Orange;
    private Color _Color4 = Color.LightSteelBlue;

    public Color TopColor
    {
        get { return _Color1; }
        set { _Color1 = value; }
    }
    public Color BottomColor
    {
        get { return _Color1; }
        set { _Color1 = value; }
    }
    public Color FocusColor
    {
        get { return _Color3; }
        set { _Color3 = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, _Color1, _Color2, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
        _Color1 = _Color3;
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
        _Color1 = _Color4;
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    public GradientButton()
    {

    }
}
```

The control is made and when ai place it on a form in design mode the gradient is LightSteelBlue to white as I would expect. However when I run the form the button changes to Orange to white whether it is clicked or not. How can I aceive this

Comment: Well, you set the focus color to orange, don't you?

Comment: What does the form look like? If the button is orange when the form is displayed, that would make me think that the button has the lowest tab index and is therefore initially focused.